# How do I perform a POST request properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postman

Working on a simple API. Managed to get the GET & DELETE requests working, but I have some issues with the POST request. Pretty sure this is a noobie mistake, but I'm missing the logic here.

This is the file where all the routes are defined.

```
import express from 'express';    
import fs from 'fs';

const router = express.Router();

'use strict';
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('api/resources/vehicles.json');
let vehicles = JSON.parse(rawdata);
let vehiclesArray = vehicles.vehicles;

let data = JSON.stringify(vehicles);
fs.writeFileSync('api/resources/vehicles.json', data);

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json(vehiclesArray);
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    res.status(200).send(vehiclesArray[(id-1)]);
});

router.delete('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    const removedVehicle = vehiclesArray.splice(id, 1);
    res.status(200).json({
        message: `Vechicle ${removedVehicle} with id ${id} was removed`
    });
});

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let id = vehiclesArray.length + 1;
    
    const vehicle = { 
        "id" : id, 
        "type" : req.params.type, 
        "brand" : req.params.brand, 
        "model" : req.params.model, 
        "production_year" : req.params.production_year, 
        "kilometers_driven" : req.params.kilometers_driven, 
        "price" : req.params.price
    };
    
    res.status(201).send({
    message: `POSTed new vehicle: ${vehicle}`,
    vehicle: vehicle
});
    res.status(201).send(vehiclesArray.push(vehicle));
    
});

export default router;
```

Inside my POST method I defined the vehicle, but once I try sending it I get the following in Postman, namely a confirmation of an added object and the object, but only with the id property
[image]

Can someone please give me a hint maybe on what I'm doing wrong? Do I also need a class declaration? Thanks!

Comment: You are displaying an object rather than something within that object if that makes sense? Try doing something like ````POSTed new vehicle: ${vehicle.type} - ${vehicle.brand}````

Comment: Why are you sending a _raw_ post body with that kind of content? Do you actually have a server-side parser, that understands _that_ format? You should probably be sending this as `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the API documentation for `params`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params):

> This property is an object containing properties mapped to the named route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route /user/:name, then the “name” property is available as req.params.name. This object defaults to {}.

Now look at your route.

> ```
> router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
> ```

You don't have any params there. So that can't be the right thing.

---

Now look at your Postman screenshot you are filling out data on the tab labelled **Body**.

Go back to the API document and skim through the list of properties.

[`req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) is listed there and says:

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

---

So set up a body-parsing middleware, then change the data you are POSTing so it is actually in that format (your screenshot shows you are entering raw data which is almost-but-not-quite-JSON so you need to fix that), make sure that you go into the Headers section and set the `Content-Type` header to describe the format you are sending, then look at `req.body` instead of `req.params`.

Comment: thanks for the input. 
I installed the body-parser and included it in my code.
Then I modified my post function:
- router.post('/:id', (req, res, next), old router.post('/', (req, res, next) 
- changed the req.param* to req.body* in the post function body.
As a last step, I changed the body type in Postman to x-www-form-urlencoded.
Will post more details as a reply to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

As advised by @Quentin:
I installed the body-parser and included it in my code.

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
router.use(express.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Then I changed the req.param* to req.body* in the post function body.

```
router.post('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let id = vehiclesArray.length + 1;
    
    const vehicle = { 
        "id" : id, 
        "type" : req.body.type, 
        "brand" : req.body.brand, 
        "model" : req.body.model, 
        "production_year" : req.body.production_year, 
        "kilometers_driven" : req.body.kilometers_driven, 
        "price" : req.body.price
    };
    
    res.status(201).send({vehicle: vehicle});
    res.status(201).send(vehiclesArray.push(vehicle));  
    
});
```

As a last step, I changed the body type in Postman to x-www-form-urlencoded.
POST below , localhost:3000/vehicles/:id
[image: Upon completing the]

GET below, just to check if the object was indeed added:
[image]

Also helpful in my endeavor:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: Don't use `body-parser`. As [the documentation for req.body](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) says, body parsing middleware is built into Express now.

Comment: @Quentin Checked again, I missed that for some reason. Removed body-parser, using only express. Thanks!